# How can I get past file length limit?

Tags: linux, file, awk, filenames

I am trying to parse 50+ files in a shell script in a single call like the following,

```
for i in {0..49}
do
    _file_list="$_file_list $_srcdir01/${_date_a[$i]}.gz"
done
eval zcat "$_file_list" | awk '{sum += 1} END {print sum;}'
```

But when I do this, I get the 'file name too long' error with zcat.

The reason I am trying to do this in a single call is because to my knowledge, awk cannot retain information from previous call. And I have to go through the entire list by considering it as a whole (e.g. finding a unique word in that list)

I also don't want to combine files because each of them are large files already.

Is there a clever way to solve this or Do I need to split the call and write out the intermediate results along the way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pipe directly from a loop:

```
for date in "${_date_a[@]}"
do
  zcat "$_srcdir01/$date.gz"
done | awk '{sum += 1} END {print sum;}'
```

---

In any case, that code shouldn't give that error as posted.

Since your example is not complete or self-contained, I added some code to initialize datafiles to test:

```
$ cat testscript
_srcdir01="./././././././././././././././././././"
_date_a=(foo{0001..0050})
for file in "${_date_a[@]}"
do
  echo "hello world" | gzip > "$file.gz"
done

for i in {0..49}
do
    _file_list="$_file_list $_srcdir01/${_date_a[$i]}.gz"
done
eval zcat "$_file_list" | awk '{sum += 1} END {print sum;}'
```

Running it generates a bunch of test data and correctly sums the number of lines:

```
$ bash testscript
50
```

I can reproduce your issue if I e.g. remove the `eval`:

```
$ bash testscript
(...)/foo0045.gz ./././././././././././././././././././/foo0046.gz ././././././.
/././././././././././././/foo0047.gz ./././././././././././././././././././/foo0
048.gz ./././././././././././././././././././/foo0049.gz ./././././././././././.
/./././././././/foo0050.gz: file name too long
```

So please double check that the code you post is the code you run, and not one of several other attempts you made while trying to solve it.

Comment: If you remove the `eval`, it would pass the whole thing as a *single* filename instead of multiple.

Comment: You can replace `awk '{sum += 1} END {print sum;}'` with `awk 'END{print NR}'` or even better just `wc -l`.

Comment: My apologies. I did have the solution that worked.. But I do like the zcat in the loop solution because its cleaner. I didn't see any end results difference but is there a difference of background behavior between `for file in "$list_of_files"
do
  zcat file
done` and `zcat long_long_list_of files` ?

Comment: @dorachan2010 What's background behavior?

Answer (score -1):

```
$ awk '{sum += 1} END {print sum}' files...
```

will work, but perhaps you just need to use `wc -l`

Manually building the file list is unnecessary,

```
$ zcat path/to/files{1..49} | awk ...
```

will work as well.

Comment: This is obviously a minimal example. And `awk` can't operate directly on compressed files.